# C# How to change Xml node values using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I replace the node value `some value` with another value using Linq.
Finally I need a string with the replaced value.

Xml:

```
<ROOT>
  <A>
    <A1>
      <elementA1></elementA1>
    </A1>
    <A2>
      <elementA2>some value</elementA2>
    </A2>
  </A>
</ROOT>
```

C#:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ROOT>
                                        <A>
                                          <A1>
                                            <elementA1></elementA1>
                                          </A1>
                                          <A2>
                                            <elementA2>Some value</elementA2>
                                          </A2>
                                        </A>
                                      </ROOT>");

xDoc.Elements("ROOT")
             .Elements("A")
             .Elements("A2")
             .Elements("elementA2")
             .Select(e => e.Value).ToList().ForEach(e => /* change the value */);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `XPathSelectElement` method for this:

```
var newValue = "New value";

var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<ROOT>
    <A>
        <A1>
            <elementA1></elementA1>
        </A1>
        <A2>
            <elementA2>Some value</elementA2>
        </A2>
    </A>
</ROOT>");

xDoc.XPathSelectElement("/ROOT/A/A2/elementA2").SetValue(newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't select the Value from all the nodes, just get the nodes themselves and change the Value property.